# MySQL Performance ORDERBY datetime on single table

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, select, query-performance

I have a MySql Events table like so:

```
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| EventId             | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ControllerId        | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| EventTypeId         | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| DateTime            | datetime(3)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| InputId             | int(11)      | YES  | MUL |         |                |
...
| AdditionalInfo      | text         | YES  |     |         |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

It's got 200M records in it at the moment and it's been running file. To keep the speed up, I don't query it with any joins, but now I am starting to hit a few long running queries. An example of a slow running query is like so:

```
SELECT E.* 
FROM Event E
WHERE (E.EventTypeId != 4 OR (E.EventTypeId = 4 AND E.InputId IS NOT NULL)) 
AND E.EventTypeId != 27 AND E.EventTypeId != 12  
AND E.ControllerId in (5190, 5191, 5192, 5193)
ORDER BY E.DateTime DESC
LIMIT 0, 200
```

That query takes over 5min! The important (I think) part of the explain comes out like so:

```
"key_length": "7",
"rows_examined_per_scan": 180071,
"rows_produced_per_join": 125770,
"filtered": "0.06",
"cost_info": {
    "read_cost":    "284389.84",
    "eval_cost":    " 25154.17",
    "prefix_cost":  "309544.01",
    "data_read_per_join": "20M"
},
```

Now if I remove the `ORDER BY E.DateTime DESC` at the end of the query it takes about 0.1s to complete. I already have an index on DateTime.

I think I understand the concept that the server has to read over all the 180k? rows returned by the `WHERE` clauses to sort them before returning it to the client, but why does it take sooo long? Is there anything I can do about it? Would a composite index help here?

Comment: Well that's a lot of records for the database to traverse and order, try narrowing your limit to a smaller amount?!

Comment: The query is for "recent events" displayed to the user, and they have a selectable amount of recent events, 200 is the max, and default is 20. I'd have _some_ users hitting the roof if I took away the option to view 200 recent events.

Comment: Isn't this a bit like `eventtypeid NOT IN(4,27,12) OR (...)`

Comment: Yes it is, I hadn't considered that - though it is mentioned in the answer, thank you. Have amended it to `WHERE (E.EventTypeId != 4 OR (E.InputId IS NOT NULL)) AND E.EventTypeId NOT IN (12, 27)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should not take 5 minutes to sort 180k rows, unless your hardware is really, really slow.  For this query:

```
SELECT E.* 
FROM Event E
WHERE (E.EventTypeId <> 4 OR (E.EventTypeId = 4 AND E.InputId IS NOT NULL)
      )  AND
      E.EventTypeId NOT IN (12, 27) AND
      E.ControllerId in (5190, 5191, 5192, 5193)
ORDER BY E.DateTime DESC
LIMIT 0, 200;
```

You might try an index `(ControllerId, EventTypeId, InputId)`.  However, I'm guessing this will not be very good.

One possibility is to use the above index and then do one controller at a time:

```
(SELECT E.* 
 FROM Event E
 WHERE (E.EventTypeId <> 4 OR (E.EventTypeId = 4 AND E.InputId IS NOT NULL)
       )  AND
       E.EventTypeId NOT IN (12, 27) AND
       E.ControllerId  = 5190
 ORDER BY E.DateTime DESC
 LIMIT 0, 200
) UNION ALL
(SELECT E.* 
 FROM Event E
 WHERE (E.EventTypeId <> 4 OR (E.EventTypeId = 4 AND E.InputId IS NOT NULL)
       )  AND
       E.EventTypeId NOT IN (12, 27) AND
       E.ControllerId  = 5191
 ORDER BY E.DateTime DESC
 LIMIT 0, 200
) 
. . . 
ORDER BY DateTime DESC
LIMIT 0, 200;
```

The index can be used more effectively for each of the subqueries.

Comment: That has dramatically improved the speed of the query, (bringing it down to under 2s) and I feel like an idiot for not trying querying them separately! Thank you, I'll probably implement the separate queries in my data layer rather than the SQL.

Comment: Oh and I forgot to add, it's running on a AWS m4.large instance using SSD. I know it's not up there, but it's not slow by any means. Maybe this query was slow because there is a constant stream of `INSERT`s

Comment: I doubt it impacts performance but the `E.EventTypeId = 4` condition is actually redundant.

Comment: That's a very good point, I hadn't noticed that. I will amend the query in my code, thanks.

Comment: @Blag This is the best reference I could find really quickly with a proof. I don't think there's a universal name for the identity `A + ~AB = A + B` except to call it a redundancy law. https://www.nayuki.io/page/boolean-algebra-laws

Comment: @Blag There's no issue with returning `<> 4 and IS NOT NULL`

Comment: @shawnt00 My bad, you're right, miss-read the query ;) (i delete as it's false)

Answer (score 0):

Your fear of `JOINs` is misplaced.  Sure, some `JOINs` are costly, but some others are much slower by avoiding `JOIN`.

What you have here is a query that cannot be optimized by changing/adding an index.

Without `ORDER BY`, it quickly scans *part* of the table, finding 200 rows and quitting.  With `ORDER BY`, it must scan the entire table, sort, *then* peel off 200 rows.

Gordon's index is probably the best thing to do.  However, it means building the `UNION` dynamically if the `IN` list is dynamic.

Newer versions of MySQL will make better use of his 3-column `INDEX` because the filtering is now being done entirely in the InnoDB engine instead of bouncing back to the generic 'handler'.

This can be simplified

```
(E.EventTypeId != 4 OR (E.EventTypeId = 4 AND E.InputId IS NOT NULL))
```

to
    (E.EventTypeId != 4 OR E.InputId IS NOT NULL)

but it won't speed things up enough to notice.

Please use `SHOW CREATE TABLE`; it is more descriptive than `DESCRIBE`.

`INT` allows for a huge range of +/-2 billion.  Do you need that many ids?  It takes 4 bytes.  Consider other sizes, such as `SMALLINT UNSIGNED` (2-bytes, 0..65K).  Shrinking the table size has some impact on performance.

Do you really need `E.*`?  If you don't need all columns, spelling out the ones you do need will run faster; in some cases noticeably faster.

One more thing...  If you are "paginating", then there is a trick for what to do with the `UNION` + `LIMIT` + `OFFSET`; see [*here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/pagination#pagination_and_union)

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't seem like you've read the question very well. I don't have a fear of JOINs, it's just faster in my use case here to not use them, I make heavy use of the cache in it's place.




Also your comment about simplifying the WHERE conditions is a repeat of other comments on this page, you seem to have written exactly what I said I already changed it to in a comment a week ago.

Comment: Unfortunately, although not listed here, there are plenty of other columns in the events table with foreign keys, all which are looked in a similar manner. So I'd have to create quite a few indexes on a table with 200 million rows where there isn't strong consensus it would help.

I do require all columns to display the event to the user yes, thank you. In regards to the Ids, as already stated in the question I have 200 million rows in it already.